# how to get local characters inside json array

Tags: php, json

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

I'm trying to use JSON between javascript, php and mysql.

```
<?php

$str = "ČAŠA***ĆAO***ŽILET***DOGAĐAJ";

$arr = explode('***', $str);

$jsonarr = json_encode($arr);

echo $jsonarr . "<br><br>";

$phparr = json_decode($jsonarr);

print_r($phparr);
```

Result:

```
["\u010cA\u0160A","\u0106AO","\u017dILET","DOGA\u0110AJ"]

Array ( [0] => ČAŠA [1] => ĆAO [2] => ŽILET [3] => DOGAĐAJ )
```

Is there a way to get this:

```
["ČAŠA","ĆAO","ŽILET","DOGAĐAJ"]
```

Or maybe so great JSON is only english speaking?

Comment: The unicode characters are escaped so that they are more likely to survive the bizarre things that can happen to data in-transit. When it is decoded you will have the same UTF8 strings that you fed into the encoder. If you are *absolutely certain* that you don't want this protection you can use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag for `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Sammitch, what kind of bizarre things?

Comment: The broad strokes of it is that people are really bad at reading documentation and adhering to standards. One of the favorites from people in PHP-land is "I am sending/accepting UTF8 data, therefore I must use `utf8_[en|de]code()`!" which is not at all what those poorly-named functions are for, and suddenly your data is corrupted because all high-order bytes have been ham-fistedly converted to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag to `json_encode`

Replace

```
$jsonarr = json_encode($arr);
```

with

```
$jsonarr = json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

here is [list](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) of `json_encode` constants